# Windows Forms show string letter by letter

Tags: c#, winforms, sleep

So in my visual C# project I have a `TextBox`, where a system response gets shown, and I want it to be displayed adding characters one by one, not the whole string at the same time. I want to create some kind of typing illusion.

For now I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= response.Length; i++)
{
    textBox2.Text = response.Substring(0, i);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

But this one waits the whole given time and then gives out the whole string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` is blocking the UI thread, so it cannot update.  Try awaiting `Task.Delay` instead and making your code async/await.

Comment: Try use: backgroundworker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use asynchrony:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= response.Length; i++)
{
    textBox2.Text = response.Substring(0, i);
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Don't forget to add the `async` keyword to scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is just sample (written with WPF) how can you achieve this. You can easily adopt it for winforms.

```
var form = new Window();
var tb = new TextBox();

form.Content = tb;
form.Show();

var str = "alk;lfkdsfj;slfhjs;idjhf;lksdjf;klsdjf;'lkjds;lfksd";
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var c in str.ToCharArray())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        form.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            tb.Text += c;
        });
    }
});
```

UPD.
For windows forms it can be a tricky and more complicated that async/await answer. But, anyway, I can show how to do this without async stuff

```
void Main()
{
    var form = new MyForm();    
    form.Show();    
}

class MyForm : Form
{
    private TextBox tb;

    public MyForm()
    {
        tb = new TextBox(); 
        tb.Width = 300;
        this.Controls.Add(tb);


        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "go";
        btn.Width = 300;        
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            tb.Text = string.Empty;
            var str = "alk;lfkdsfj;slfhjs;idjhf;lksdjf;klsdjf;'lkjds;lfksd";
            SetText d = SetTextToTb;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var c in str.ToCharArray())
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    tb.Invoke(d, c);
                }
            });
        };
    }

    public delegate void SetText(char text);
    void SetTextToTb(char text)
    {
        tb.Text += text;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any analog of form.Dispatcher.Invoke for winforms?